# how do i reduce the words in this sentence?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

How do I reduce the words in the following sentence?

> The sort procedure requires an average of 30% of the total time, and the search procedure requires an average of 40% of the total time.

Up to now, I have:

> 1. The sort procedure and the search procedure require an average of 30% and 40% of the total time correspondingly.
> 2. The sort and search procedure require an average of 30% and 40% of the total time correspondingly.

Do you have better ones?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for writing advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

> The sort procedure averages 30% of the total time, 
>       while the search procedure averages 40% of the total time.

or,

> On average, the sort procedure and the search procedure take 30% and 40%, 
>       respectively, of the total time.

Comment: In the second example, "with regards to" can be profitably replaced with "of".

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your sentence, hope it is helpful.

> Of the total time, averagely, 30% and 40% will be taken by the sort procedure and the search procedure, respectively.